# Polling IBM Websphere Message Queue

Tags: .net, architecture, ibm-mq

**Requirement**: Build a .NET based application that can reads messages at regular interval from a IBM Websphere Message Queue and save those messages in database

**My solution**: I created a windows service application that polls the Message Queue at certain interval and process the data.

*Problem with polling is that application process is delayed by the polling interval. I cannot set the interval too short as I am not sure how much data there will be in the Message Queue and how long it will take to process.*

**Question**: What would be better way to process data from a WebSphere Message Queue using .NET? How will I be able to process the data as soon as arrive in Message queue?

Comment: Why does the application not follow the usual pattern of `GET` with wait?

Comment: @T.Rob Not sure what you meant. The application currently waits for 30s and then gets and process message from MQ.

Comment: Question says "application process is delayed by the polling interval". Normally, the application issues a `GET` and specifies a `WAIT` interval. When a message arrives, there is zero delay because the app is waiting on it.  If the `WAIT` expires, the app gets `RC=2033` and loops back with another `GET` and `WAIT`.   However, if an application issues a `GET` with no `WAIT`, then sleeps for 30 seconds, there is a long delay while the app is asleep.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is asynchronous messaging. This works by registering a callback, which the MQ client will then invoke when a message is available. Take a look at the Knowledge Center page:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023050_.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IBM Message Service Client for .NET (a.k.a. XMS .NET)`. This client provides message listener feature (basically a callback as Tim mentioned above). Message listener will be invoked when a message that matches consumer selection criteria arrives in a queue.

If you are using MQ v7.1 or above, then XMS .NET is installed with MQ client. If you are at lower version, then you need to download [IA9H](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24011756) support pack. You will need to reference IBM.XMS assembly in your application. Samples are shipped with product to demonstrate a number features including Message Listener.

Look at SimpleAsyncConsumer.cs sample shipped with product for details.